# Cauchy Projection formula on Convex Bodies

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Suppose $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a convex body i.e. a compact convex set with a non-empty interior. Additionally assume that $\mathbf{0} \in K$, where $\mathbf{0}$ is the zero-vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Now, a well known concept in convex body theory is the *Brightness Function* of a convex body $K$ (see cited paper below). In summary, we quote the following from the paper:

> The brightness function of K
> $$
> b_{K}(u)=V\left(K \mid u^{\perp}\right)
> $$
> for $u \in S^{n-1}$. *Cauchy's projection formula* (the case $i=n-1$ of $[10,(\mathrm{A.} 45), \mathrm{p} .408]$ ) states that
> $$
> b_{K}(u)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{S^{n-1}}|u \cdot v| d S(K, v)
> $$
> for $u \in S^{n-1}$

Here $K \mid u^{\perp}$ denotes the (orthogonal) projection of $K$ onto
the orthogonal subspace of $\{ u \}$, where $u \in S^{n-1}$ (i.e. a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^{n -1}$ passing through the origin).

Based on this I have a few related questions:

1. I wanted to check if $K \mid u^{\perp}$ is a convex body in $\mathbb{R}^{n -1}$ i.e. a compact convex set with non-empty interior? I expect it to be, but wasn't sure how to go about proving it (particularly that the non-empty interior is preserved under orthogonal image).
2. If we scale $K$ i.e. $K^{'} = \alpha K$, for some $\alpha > 0$, then does $b_{K^{'}}(u) = \alpha^{n - 1} b_{K}(u)$. This is a conjecture, but can it be shown formally using the Cauchy projection formula?

*Campi, Stefano; Gardner, Richard J.; Gronchi, Paolo; Kiderlen, Markus*, [**Lightness functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2012.08.015), Adv. Math. 231, No. 6, 3118-3146 (2012). [ZBL1261.52002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1261.52002)..

Comment: To answer your first question, projection is a continuous, open, linear map. Being continuous, it preserves compactness. Being open, it will map interior points to interior points. Being linear, it will preserve compactness. Particularly, if you take a ball contained in $K$, add the appropriate multiple of $u$ so that the centre lies in $u^\perp$ (note that this won't change the projection), then the projection of this ball will be the intersection of the ball with $u^\perp$, which is a ball in $u^\perp$.

Comment: @user837206 - I appreciate your insight. I could you please explain why it is an open map in a rigorous sense? Could you please provide a proof that an intersection of the ball with $u^{\perp}$ is a ball in $u^{\perp}$, especially the translation by a scaled multiple of $u$. Any details written down would be great to appreciate your answer better.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer in response to a comment.

First, I want to deal with the question of why the intersection of a ball in $\Bbb{R}^n$ with $u^\perp$ is a ball in $u^\perp$. Basically, the answer is "by definition".

Remember that $u^\perp$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$, and it inherits its norm from $\Bbb{R}^n$. Of course, it's isometrically isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$, but in order for that statement to mean anything, it needs to be a normed linear space in its own right. A subspace is always endowed with norm of the superspace, in that we simply restrict the norm function's domain to the subspace. So, we have
$$x \in B_{u^\perp}[y; r] \iff x \in u^\perp \text{ and }\|x - y\| \le r \iff x \in B_{\Bbb{R}^n}[y; r] \cap u^\perp.$$
This holds similarly for open balls, of course!

Now, let's say that we have a convex body $K$. I'm assuming you're happy with projection being both linear and continuous, hence $K \mid u^\perp$ is both convex and compact. Since $K$ has non-empty interior, some there exists some subset of $K$ of the form $B_{\Bbb{R}^n}(y; s)$, where $s > 0$.

Let $K' = K - \langle y, u\rangle u = \{k - \langle y, u \rangle u : k \in K\}$. Then $K'$ is simply a translation of $K$, and hence still a convex body.

Recall that the projection function is linear (again) and that it maps $u$ (and hence all its multiples) to $0$. So, the projection of $k - \langle y, u \rangle$ onto $u^\perp$ is the same as the projection of $k$ onto $u^\perp$, and so
$$K' \mid u^\perp = K \mid u^\perp.$$

Now, since $B_{\Bbb{R}^n}(y; s) \subseteq K$, we have
$$B_{\Bbb{R}^n}(y - \langle y, u \rangle u; s) = B_{\Bbb{R}^n}(y; s) - \langle y, u \rangle u \subseteq K'.$$
The centre, $y - \langle y, u \rangle u$, lies in $u^\perp$ (you can calculate this for yourself). As discussed before,
$$B_{\Bbb{R}^n}(y - \langle y, u \rangle u; s) \cap u^\perp = B_{u^\perp}(y - \langle y, u \rangle u; s),$$
and since the projection onto $u^\perp$ fixes every vector in $u^\perp$,
\begin{align*}
B_{u^\perp}(y - \langle y, u \rangle u; s) &= B_{u^\perp}(y - \langle y, u \rangle u; s) \mid u^\perp \\
&\subseteq B_{\Bbb{R}^n}(y - \langle y, u \rangle u; s) \mid u^\perp \\
&\subseteq K' \mid u^\perp \\
&= K \mid u^\perp.
\end{align*}

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you again for your clarifications. They are helpful. Since I'm new to this, I had some  quick follow ups. I can see that compactness is preserved by continuity. How is convexity preserved by linearity here? Also what motivated you to translate $K$ in this very specific way i.e. could this have been shown without translation? I think of the projection on the hyperplane as a "shadow". I guess what you are saying is that moving the original body simply translates the "shadow" I have to go through the details of your remaining proof and may post a quick follow up on that later.

Comment: Oh, I see the convexity preservation under linear image. It is just from the definition of convexity. That part is clear now.

Comment: Also in $x \in u^{\perp}$ and $\| x - y\| \leq r$, isn't $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n -1}$, and $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, so how does this norm expression make sense here i.e. aren't $x, y$ of different dimensions? Sorry if this is straightforward.

Comment: @user4687531 Yes, the translation of $K$ will correspond to translation of the "shadow". In this case, I moved the body parallel to $u$, which is parallel to the "light rays", and thus the "shadow" doesn't even move! By moving $K$ parallel to $u$, we obtain the same projection. As for the motivation, I guess some of that is experience, but I had an image in my head of a 3-D ball in $\Bbb{R}^3$, projecting onto a plane. I can see that it projects to a disc, the question was, which disc? I quickly realised that the centre of the disc was the projection of the centre of the ball onto the plane.

Comment: @user4687531 As for your next question, remember that $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$ is not literally a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$, it is just isometrically isomorphic to a subspace (in fact, many subspaces!) of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Indeed, the two spaces share precisely zero points in common; one contains $n$-tuples, while the other contains $(n-1)$-tuples. The space $u^\perp$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$, which implies it is a subset. That is, every element of $u^\perp$ belongs to $\Bbb{R}^n$ (and thus **not** $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$). So, it totally makes sense to write $\|x - y\|$.